# Ошибка unable to read memory c HWND

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня игра сапер. При нажатии на клавишу выбора уровня сложности запускается примерно такой код

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
        ShowWindow(easyLevel, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(middleLevel, SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(hardLevel, SW_HIDE);
        Field myField = Field(10, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < myField.getSizeX(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myField.getSizeY(); j++) {
                if (myField.getField()[i][j].isBomb()) {
                    myField.getField()[i][j].setButton(CreateWindow("button", "b", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 370 + j * 25, 250 + i * 25, 25, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)(i + j + 1), ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL));
                }
                else {
                    myField.getField()[i][j].setButton(CreateWindow("button", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 370 + j * 25, 250 + i * 25, 25, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)(i + j + 1), ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->hInstance, NULL));
                }
                UpdateWindow(myField.getField()[i][j].getButton());
            }
        }
    }
```

Этот код отображает поле на экране. Но при вызове getField возникает исключение Access violation reading location.

Comment: А в чем проблема-то выражается?

Comment: Мало ли что пишет дебаггер. Вопрос в том, что работает неправильно?

Comment: И с чего вы взяли, что ваш вылет "при вызове getField" имеет какое-то отношение к `HWND`?

Comment: уже понял, что ошибка происходит при вызове CreateWindow, но не пойму, почему

Answer (score 4):

`HWND` может быть определен как `typedef void* HWND`, или быть структурой, в которой есть указатель.

При этом значения `HWND` - это маленькие числа, и естественно отладчик не может прочитать память по этому указателю, потому что на самом деле `HWND` это не указатель и он никуда не указывает.